# Error: New Relic Instrumentation Error in Firebase Auth Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, newrelic

I am getting an error related to Firebase Chat Demo,

This error is coming when I am creating FirebaseAuth Instance from

**FirebaseAuth.getInstance();**

I have uploaded project on **Github.com** so you can look at it. The project was running perfect before one month and since I have not opened it, but now it is giving this type of errors

**Project Link**: https://github.com/raghavsatyadev/FirebaseChatDemo

Please don't give suggestions as: project clean, reinstall app, uninstall app as I have already **recloned** whole project and uninstalled previous app.

**STACK TRACE:**

```
> FATAL EXCEPTION: pool-4-thread-1
Process: com.firebasechatdemo, PID: 31569
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/newrelic/agent/android/instrumentation/JSONObjectInstrumentation;
at com.google.firebase.iid.zzs.zzc(Unknown Source)
at com.google.firebase.iid.zzr.zza(Unknown Source)
at com.google.firebase.iid.zzj.getToken(Unknown Source)
at com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId.getToken(Unknown Source)
at com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId.zzKg(Unknown Source)
at com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService.zza(Unknown Source)
at com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService.handleIntent(Unknown Source)
at com.google.firebase.iid.zzc.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.newrelic.agent.android.instrumentation.JSONObjectInstrumentation" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.firebasechatdemo-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.firebasechatdemo-1/lib/arm, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:380)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
at com.google.firebase.iid.zzs.zzc(Unknown Source) 
at com.google.firebase.iid.zzr.zza(Unknown Source) 
at com.google.firebase.iid.zzj.getToken(Unknown Source) 
at com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId.getToken(Unknown Source) 
at com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId.zzKg(Unknown Source) 
at com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService.zza(Unknown Source) 
at com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService.handleIntent(Unknown Source) 
at com.google.firebase.iid.zzc.run(Unknown Source) 
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133) 
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607) 
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
```

Comment: I think my google-play-services library in Android SDK got corrupted. I redownloaded it and the problem got solved

Answer (score 0):

Try as below:

Delete build folder of project-level and app-level.
Re-run the project.

Check if this works..

Comment: it did no affect on my Linux system, however I cloned the Repo on Windows PC and project ran successfully , maybe this is because of some firebase maintenance as I cloned after almost 8 hours.